# Graph of Function With Translation

Tags: graphing-functions

I tutor a student and the question they have is: " Give an example of a function whose horizontal translation gives the same resulting graph as the vertical translation ".
My work: I thought of several well known collegiate functions like linear, quadratic, exponential and they don't work. What about $f(x) = x$ ? For example, the horizontal shift right by $1$ unit gives the same graph as vertical shift down by $1$ unit. I wonder if there can be other functions? I haven't spent enough time on this but preliminary that's what I got. Any input is appreciated. Thanks, WY.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition is that $f(x+1) = f(x) + 1$. There are lots of functions that satisfy it, like choose your favorite function on $[0, 1)$ and extend from there.